# Thymeleaf - class method in th:text

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have domain class:

```
public class Note
{
    private Date date;
    // other fields;

    public void setDate( Date date )
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate ()
    {
        return date;
    }
}
```

but in Thymeleaf I dont want to use field date directly. Normally I could have one method like

```
public String getFormattedDate()
{
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

without field named formattedDate ( I dont need it ).

But .. I cant do that :

```
th:text = "${note.formattedDate}"
```

I could add a field named formattedDate + getters and setters but in my opinion it's very bad solution, because I need only the value of formatted date.

Do you have any solution of this problem ?

Comment: Please, post the exception and error details. `th:text = "${note.formattedDate}"` is a valid expression. I guess your error is somewhere else.

Comment: Error: "Could not find a setter for property formattedDate in class eniupage.domain.News"

But why my expression is valid ? If Iuse "${note.date}" it works fine but with ugly formatting.

Comment: You can also do: `th:text = "${note.getFormattedDate()}` or `th:text = "${#dates.format(note.date, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')}"` see [Appendix B: Expression Utility Objects - Dates](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#dates).

Comment: Thanks for link; 

${note.getFormattedDate()}  isn't working.  It is hibernate's exception: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter.

Comment: Error states that something is trying to set the value `formattedDate` or interprets `formattedDate` as a property because the method is `get...`. Maybe the full stacktrace could help. But but I'm pretty sure it's not a Thymeleaf problem. I currently use getter methods that don't have any setter nor attribute.

Comment: If it's hibernate you can annotate the method with `@Transient`. But imho I prefer the `#dates` approach.

Comment: Ok I have solution :)

I used @Transient from java.beans ! Hibernate needs it from javax.persistence !

But thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use

```
${#dates.format(date, YOUR_PATTERN, #locale)}
```